# Cannot successfully execute AJAX script to call function.php specific function. Using XAMPP localhost to test

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, javascript

I've been trying to grasp AJAX for the past 12 hours and i'm slowly losing it. How can I simply pass two basic input dates via form or any other means, *not* refresh the page, and have it execute the PHP function which contains a JS script?

Before I even pass the values to the script I just wanna echo the array of data I'm passing to see if...well ajax is working. The form button just refreshes the page regardless, so I don't think AJAX is even kicking in at all. I'm trying on the https://localhost for xampp. I don't know what's missing to stop the refresh and kick in the ajax script over the button.

Appreciate any insight.

functions.php

```
<?php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_parent_styles');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_lineChartCustom', 'lineChartCustomCreate');
add_action('wp_ajax_lineChartCustom', 'lineChartCustomCreate');

function lineChartCustomCreate(){

    if ( isset( $_POST['dataForPHP'])){
        //echo data array
    echo $dataForPHP;
    //<script>Some chart generating script using the data array</script>
    }
}
?>
```

page-template.php

```
<?php
    echo "<form id='my-form'>
        Select Date Range:
        <input type='date' name='date1'>
        <input type='date' name='date2'>
        <input type='submit' id='submit' value='submit'>
        </form>";
?>
<script>
        jQuery('#submit').on('click', function() {

            let formData = jQuery('#my-form').serializeArray(); // retrieves the form's data as an array

           jQuery.ajax({
                     url: ajaxurl, // default ajax url of wordpress
                     type: 'POST',
                     data: {
                         action: 'lineChartCustom', // use this action to handle the event
                         dataForPHP: formData // this is your form's data that is going to be submitted to PHP by the name of dataForPHP                
                 });
             });
         });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `wp_die();` at the end of your php function.

But you could also send the response with `wp_send_json`, `wp_send_json_error` or `wp_send_json_success`. These functions also terminate the function execution.

Comment: It's because i omitted the die function that it's not executing? It's still refreshing the page which is sort of the cue for me that ajax isn't doing anything

Comment: Yes, you need to end the PHP function in one way or the other to return a proper response. I don't know, if you know this already, but please note that you won't be seeing the `echo / var_dump() / print_r()` on the page, but in browser dev tools > network > ajax call's response tab. And also as @nmr pointed out `onclick` must return `false` or call `.preventDefault()` to prevent browser from submitting the form and stopping your javascript from kicking in.

Answer (score 0):

The page is refreshed because you are sending the form synchronously (traditionally). To  send the form using ajax your function hooked to `onclick` must return `false` or call `.preventDefault()` on submit event.

```
jQuery( "#my-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //
    // your code...
});

// --- or --- 

jQuery('#submit').on('click', function() {
    // ....
    return false;
});
```

### Edit:

Move your javascript code to separate file (e.g. `myscript.js`). include that file on page using [`wp_enqueue_scripts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) ([hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)). in the code you used `ajaxurl` but you have not defined it anywhere. [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) is used to pass values from php to javascript, this way you will set the address for ajax in `ajx_url` variable.

*page-template.php:*

```
<?php
echo "<form id='my-form'>
    Select Date Range:
    <input type='date' name='date1'>
    <input type='date' name='date2'>
    <input type='submit' id='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>";
?>
```

*myscript.js:*

```
jQuery('#submit').on('click', function() {

    let formData = jQuery('#my-form').serializeArray(); // retrieves the form's data as an array

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url, // default ajax url of wordpress
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'lineChartCustom', // use this action to handle the event
            dataForPHP: formData // this is your form's data that is going to be submitted to PHP by the name of dataForPHP                
        }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( msg );
    });
    return false;
});
```

*functions.php*

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-javascript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/myscript.js',  array('jquery'), '', true );

    // in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url
    wp_localize_script( 'my-javascript', 'ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ) );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_parent_styles');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_lineChartCustom', 'lineChartCustomCreate');
add_action('wp_ajax_lineChartCustom', 'lineChartCustomCreate');

function lineChartCustomCreate(){

    if ( isset( $_POST['dataForPHP']) ){
        //echo data array
        print_r($_POST['dataForPHP']);
    }
    die();
}
```

Comment: Is that the traditional method to do all ajax calls asynchronously? I had tried even with a standard  <button> rather than a <form> and the button would yet still not trigger the jquery

Comment: @Dennisio By default, `jQuery.ajax()` is asynchronous but it can be changed by the `async` parameter, [jQuery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings)

Comment: @Dennisio Check updated answer